# Screen Resolution in BlackBerry WebWorks

Tags: html, blackberry, browser, blackberry-webworks

I am new to webworks and whole BlackBerry Development and I got a question about it.
I am going to develop my app for Torch phones. As far as I know there are 3 or 4 different screen resolutions in torch series. However the aspect ratio stays the same.

So, here is the question: what should i do with layout of my html pages. Should I make it flexible by using %'s instad of px's or should I pick the smallest screen resolution and torch phones with bigger resolution will automatically make it fit? Is there any solution from RIM about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using a META viewport like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1.0">
```

For Torch devices, you may also want to include the `target-densitydpi=device-dpi` property, which allows the web engine to scale content to the current screen resolution.

Here is a sample I wrote to demo viewports. Try loading it on your devices to see how the content renders:
http://blackberry.github.com/WebWorks-Samples/kitchenSink/html/browser/viewport/viewport.html

The samples also includes sample page for the targetdensity property:
http://blackberry.github.com/WebWorks-Samples/kitchenSink/html/browser/viewport/densitydpi.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use the media queries in CSS  for example for torch 9800

@media screen and (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 480px) { … }

you can use the features to the media queries for developer app in html5

check this [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)